# How can I get rid of the app name menu bar in Android Studio 4.1.2

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

Does anyone know how to get rid of this menu bar that has the app name in Android Studio? I accidentally enabled it and have no idea how to remove it.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes with the material theme. You can easily disable it by following these steps:

1. Select *Tools* from the menu bar
2. Goto *Material Theme* -> *Material Theme Option* -> *Toggle Project Frame colours*.

[image: Image to show the path]